# Boost Asio: Catching signals without keeping an otherwise finished io_service running

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am writing a socket client-type application with boost::asio. I am doing something like the example wherein they use an `asio::signal_set` to catch signals, and in the signal handler they call `io_service::stop` to stop the client gracefully and quit the program.

However, `io_service::run` returns when there is no more work to do (or `stop` is called) and unfortunately, the `signal_set` counts as work. So, even when my client is out of work, it is still waiting on a signal to call the signal handler and the program can only end when you hit Ctrl-C or whatever. I would like it to exit when *either* a signal is received *or* the sockets quit giving work to the `io_service`, i.e. a normal exit.

Is there a way that I can get the `io_service` to keep running only as long as there is work *other* than the signal handler? (I cannot call `stop` myself because I can't know when there's no more work; only the `io_service` knows.)

Comment: There is an answer to a very similiar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675136/boost-asio-handler-that-does-not-keep-the-io-service-running , but it is a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about catching the signal yourself and stopping the `io_service` on catch?

Comment: The problem is when there is no signal, and the only thing keeping the io_service running is that it's waiting on a signal which will never come. The program should still quit.

Comment: However, if you don't use asio::signal_set but roll your own signal handler, there would be no signal work to wait for.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. The reason I did it with boost is for multiplatform support. I would prefer not to lose that if I can. Does boost offer a way of catching signals apart from asio?

Comment: @uk4321: relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219687/how-to-use-signal-set-to-terminate-boost-asio-io-service-run (see the comment)

Comment: Great idea, why didn't I think of that.

Comment: @erenon Posix signals are quite messy with respect to interrupting system calls etc. So letting boost asio catch the signals instead of the application itself increases the likelyhood, that the signals are processed cleanly.