# Boost asio handler that does not keep the io_service running

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I want to add a signal handler to my boost io_service, allowing the application to shut down cleanly when the user presses Ctrl-C. This is of course easily done by stopping the loop, something like this:

```
boost::asio::io_service service;
boost::asio::signal_set signals{ service, SIGINT, SIGTERM };

signals.async_wait(std::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::stop, &service));
```

This stops the loop normally, allowing the destructors to do their routine clean-up behaviour.

The problem is, once the application runs out of work it does not stop because the signal handler still has a handler registered and thus the io_service never stops running.

I have not found a clean way around this. I could of course do the signal handling myself and then just stop the loop, but this kind of defeats the idea of using boost (portability).

Comment: Why can't the application call `signals.cancel()` when it runs out of work?

Comment: Because the application does not know when it runs out of work. The only one that knows whether more work is available is the io_service.

Comment: Are you using `io_service` as a thread pool? What are you doing exactly?

Comment: It's just simple non-blocking IO with a listening socket and zero or more active connections and some timers for active operations that need to timeout/stop. I don't spawn any additional threads.

Comment: @MartijnOtto how does your `listening socket` "run out of work"?

Comment: Well, I don't think that all these questions are relevant at all, since they don't lead toward an answer to my question, but it is possible to tell the program to shut down when communicating with it. This will close the listening socket and also send messages to all other sockets that the system is shutting down. Then it is a matter of waiting until all current connections and timers are finished.

Comment: The application actually knows when it runs out of work because every `io_service` hook has a completion handler that gets called on a "state" change and that could be data read, data written, connection reset/aborted, deadline timer done, etc. At that moment you can wrap every logical block that operates on `io_service` in a class that counts how many hooks there are left. When the counter drops to zero, it either cancels the `signal_set` or stops the `io_service` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am probably going to hell for this, but I found a workaround to get a handler that doesn't coun't towards the number of running handlers. It seriously abuses both the work_guard boost provides, calls destructors by hand and misuses placement new, but it works.

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

template <typename HANDLER>
class unwork
{
    public:
        unwork(boost::asio::io_service &service, HANDLER &&handler) :
            _work_guard(std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(service)),
            _handler(std::forward<HANDLER>(handler))
        {
            // wait for the handler to be installed
            service.post([work_guard = _work_guard.operator->()]() {
                // remove the work guard and the handler that has now been installed
                work_guard->~work();
                work_guard->~work();
            });
        }

        unwork(const unwork &that) :
            unwork(that._work_guard->get_io_service(), that._handler)
        {}

        unwork(unwork &&that) :
            _work_guard(std::move(that._work_guard)),
            _handler(std::move(that._handler))
        {}

        ~unwork()
        {
            // was the work guard not moved out?
            if (_work_guard) {
                // add the work guard reference and the handler reference again
                new (_work_guard.operator->()) boost::asio::io_service::work{ _work_guard->get_io_service() };
                new (_work_guard.operator->()) boost::asio::io_service::work{ _work_guard->get_io_service() };
            }
        }

        template <class ...Arguments>
        auto operator()(Arguments ...parameters)
        {
            return _handler(std::forward<Arguments>(parameters)...);
        }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>  _work_guard;
        HANDLER                                         _handler;
};

// maker function, for c++ < c++17
template <typename HANDLER>
unwork<HANDLER> make_unwork(boost::asio::io_service &service, HANDLER &&handler)
{
    // create the new unwork wrapper
    return { service, std::forward<HANDLER>(handler) };
}
```

It is used by wrapping your handler in a make_unwork() call if you are using c++14. In c++17 the constructor can be used directly.

Comment: Why do you call the destructor `work_guard->~work();` twice? To reduce boost::asio's internal counter of how many work jobs are there left to do?

Comment: Yes. The work guard itself adds a reference, so we're at +1 when we want to go to -1 (to counteract the other handler). Then, in the destructor, we create it twice so that we're back at +1 until the real work guard is destroyed, leaving us at 0. Note that recent asio allows changing the counts directly, so this monstrosity is no longer needed.

Comment: Can you post an example with "changing the counts directly?" or provide a reference to where I can find documentation about it? That would really be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

In the following code, `http_server` has a "listening socket" to accept multiple connections. The listening socket constantly runs `async_accept` so the `io_service` never runs out of work. The `http_server.shutdown()` function closes the listening socket and all open connections, so the `io_service` has no more work and stops running:

```
void handle_stop(ASIO_ERROR_CODE const&, // error,
                 int, // signal_number,
                 http_server_type& http_server)
{
  std::cout << "Shutting down" << std::endl;
  http_server.shutdown();
}

...

ASIO::io_service io_service;
http_server_type http_server(io_service);

...


// The signal set is used to register termination notifications
ASIO::signal_set signals_(io_service);
signals_.add(SIGINT);
signals_.add(SIGTERM);
#if defined(SIGQUIT)
signals_.add(SIGQUIT);
#endif // #if defined(SIGQUIT)

// register the handle_stop callback
signals_.async_wait([&http_server]
  (ASIO_ERROR_CODE const& error, int signal_number)
{ handle_stop(error, signal_number, http_server); });

...

io_service.run();
std::cout << "io_service.run complete, shutdown successful" << std::endl;
```

This method also works for thread pools, see:[thread_pool_http_server.cpp](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib/tree/master/examples/server/thread_pool_http_server.cpp)